# How to set httponly cookie with kong gateway

Tags: node.js, microservices, kong

so i have a backend which contain an endpoint to set a httponly cookie when the admin login. This is the code :

```
        // Set the cookie
        response.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
            maxAge: 3.154e10,
            httpOnly: true,
        });

        response.send(this.UtilsInstance.sendOutput(message.Success, {
            accessToken : accessToken,
            username : removePasswordFromAdminData.username,
            role : removePasswordFromAdminData.role
        }));
```

And this is how the frontend side :

```
await axios
.post('http://my_url/auth/v1/admin/login/',
    {
        'username': username.value,
        'password': password.value
    }, {
        withCredentials: true
    }
);
```

Also the kong.yaml

```
plugins:
   - name: cors
   route: auth-routes
   config:
      origins:
      - http://localhost:3000
      methods:
      - GET
      - POST
      - PUT
      - DELETE
      headers:
      - Accept
      - Accept-Version
      - Authorization
      - Content-Length
      - Content-MD5
      - Content-Type
      - Date
      - X-Auth-Token
      exposed_headers:
      - X-Auth-Token
      credentials: true
      max_age: 3600
      preflight_continue: false
```

The code runs smoothly without a single error (i got the response), but i cant see the httponly cookie on dev tool after the API being called. What am i missing here?

Comment: just wanted to add some note, when i run the code without the gateway the program runs as expected. So surely something is wrong in the kong config somewhere...

Comment: Can you check the query received by kong and the one sent by kong to the browser ?